Command to create Lattix project *.ldz file from Understand *.und file
I want to use CLI of Lattix to create Lattix project *.ldz file from Understand *.und file.
https://docs.lattix.com/lattix/commandLineTools/Using_ldcupdate.html
From the docs, it looks like ldcupdate can be used to create Lattix project from Understand db but I couldn't find out the correct command with arguments.
Thank you for your help!
I tried GUI and it was OK.
But I would need to use CLI in my application.
